# What causes a server to be slow to respond when it has a very low load average?

Tags: ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu server that has recently been intermittently slow to respond - 30s+ to connect to ssh or web servers, and New Relic shows regular interruptions in the data (but no actual activity).

Every time I look at it the load average is under 0.1. I can't see signs of excessive activity in any of the services running.

If there is no sign of activity on the server how can I find what is making it slow to respond?

Comment: Sounds like a network problem.

Comment: Details about how to identify said network problem could be most helpful. In any case this error is resolved but if there was a different error that caused the same result I'm not sure how it could be tested.

Comment: It is simply not possible to narrow the problem down any further with the information provided in the question.

Comment: That is exactly why it was asked, I thought there might be some additional ways to narrow it down when all the normal steps failed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a recent issue with Ubuntu (and also a second issue that applies to certain Digital Ocean servers). DNS lookups were failing which caused delays on everything running there. It was resolved by installed updated packages with apt-get.

Full details are listed at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-the-march-2017-ubuntu-dns-resolution-issues.